# could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet with oauth

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, oauth-2.0

I am doing a rest service with java spring boot. The tables are created correctly in the database and locally test everything works correctly, but when I mount the .war in a tomcat in my vps the Fail starts.

Doing a POST request to /oatuh/ token to login throws me an exception:

```
"could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"
```

Attached image:
[image]

User Entity:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "users")
 public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7125479784396028079L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username", unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "email", unique = true)
private String email;
```

DAO:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>{

@Query("select u from UserEntity u where u.username = ?1")
public UserEntity findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Service:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserEntity user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
    System.out.println(user);

    if (user == null) {
        log.error("El usuario no existe en la base de datos.");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario inexistente en la base de datos");
    }

    return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, null);
 }
```

Comment: have you tried to specify the schema? @Table(name= "users", schema = "targetSchemaName")

Comment: What database is this?

Comment: Please provide full stacktrace.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry! I used mysql database with dialect MySQL57Dialect

`spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect`

Comment: @bobtang No, what scheme should I provide? never use schemas for my entities

Comment: @Juance your db name

Comment: @bobtang i added the schema to the entity but the problem continues

Comment: i test my app from postman, and this is send from service `{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}` could it be something wrong with the frontend?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Column(name = "lastModifiedBy")
private int lastModifiedBy;

@Column(name = "lastModifedOn")
private Date lastModifiedOn;
```

There was a typo in my code `lastModifedOn`, I changed it to `lastModifiedOn` and the issue was fixed forever.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! I couldn't see the error when my app was on Tomcat. I tried Postman and the mistake was that the authorities could not be null, if or if you need a role.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes happens with database queries, in query, the cause of the error is: the database to which the table is built is different from the database to which the configuration file is connected, and the address of the database to which the table is built is not checked carefully.

You must add scheme, example: myScheme.myTable.
greetings..